# Split a file after a certain number of unique entries

Tags: awk, terminal

Given a tab-delimited file:

```
A   12380
A   123801
A   1209
A   2035
A   4930
A   2903
B   2085
B   203801
B   240083
B   12308
B   12399
C   120303
C   1238058
C   235
D   55674
D   99683
D   2391095
D   12958
D   23804
D   5769
E   479903
E   28075
E   2310
E   6784
F   4789
F   23458
F   8976
G   9007
H   1203
H   12909
```

I want to split this after a certain number of unique entries have been seen - from a specific column. As an example, split the above file after every 3 unique entries in the first column. Producing 3 files:

```
A   12380
A   123801
A   1209
A   2035
A   4930
A   2903
B   2085
B   203801
B   240083
B   12308
B   12399
C   120303
C   1238058
C   235

D   55674
D   99683
D   2391095
D   12958
D   23804
D   5769
E   479903
E   28075
E   2310
E   6784
F   4789
F   23458
F   8976

G   9007
H   1203
H   12909
```

I have this so far:

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN { count=0; filename=1 }; x[$1]++==0 {count++}; count==3 { count=1; filename++}; {print >> filename".txt"; close(filename".txt");}' file
```

However when running this on the terminal, I get the error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    BEGIN { count=0; filename=1 }; x[$1]++==0 {count++}; count==4 { count=1; filename++}; {print >> >>>  filename".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

Why?

**EDIT**: Removing the ".txt" fixes this - however it is super slow. Any help?

Comment: @Cyrus Okay - Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(tested with given samples).

```
awk -v count=1 '
prev!=$1 && prev{
  count++
  delete a[prev]
}
count==4 && !a[$1]++{
  count=1
  print ""
}
{
  prev=$1
}
1
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk -v count=1 '           ##Starting awk program here, mentioning variable count whose value is 1.
prev!=$1 && prev{          ##Checking condition where prev NOT equal to current $1 and variable prev is NOT NULL then do following.
  count++                  ##Increment variable count with 1 here.
  delete a[prev]           ##Deleting array a value whose index is prev variable here.
}
count==4 && !a[$1]++{      ##Checking condition if count==4 and array a does not have any previous occurrence of $1 then do following.
  count=1                  ##Setting value of count to 1 here.
  print ""                 ##Printing NULL line here.
}
{
  prev=$1                  ##Setting variable prev to $1 of current line.
}
1
'  Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** To take output into output file try following.

```
awk -v count=1 -v file_count=1 '
BEGIN{
  file=file_count".txt"
}
prev!=$1 && prev{
  count++
  delete a[prev]
}
count==4 && !a[$1]++{
  count=1
  close(file)
  file_count++
  file=file_count".txt"
}
{
  prev=$1
}
{
  print $0 > (file)
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: @AnnaSchumann, Do you need to print values or need them in output files? Kindly do confirm, if output file needed then what should be there name?

Comment: Yes - I would require them in output files. Simply numbered '1.txt' '2.txt' '3.txt' and so forth.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann, where 1.txt should have 1st 3 unique values right?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann, please try my EDIT command and let me know then.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$1!=(p""){p=$1;u++}
  u>3{close(n++".txt");u=1}
  {print >(n".txt")}' n=1 file
$ cat 1.txt
A   12380
A   123801
A   1209
A   2035
A   4930
A   2903
B   2085
B   203801
B   240083
B   12308
B   12399
C   120303
C   1238058
C   235
$ cat 2.txt
D   55674
D   99683
D   2391095
D   12958
D   23804
D   5769
E   479903
E   28075
E   2310
E   6784
F   4789
F   23458
F   8976
$ cat 3.txt
G   9007
H   1203
H   12909
```